# Rescue from errors for end-users, but email me error details (Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, exception

What what is a best practice around gracefully handling (i.e. `begin...rescue...end`) errors for end-users, yet alerting me that they are happening?

**More details:**

I have a Ruby on Rails web application whose core functionality relies on several APIs (as well as some web scraping), so I need to be extra careful with handling API errors that may occur. Examples of said errors: Exceeding API concurrent usage limits, API data coming back in a format I didn't expect, web scraping gone awry, etc.

I'd like for end users to not have a bad experience if APIs falter for any of those reasons. **Here's my current setup, and I'd love to know if this is a best practice, or I'm missing anything big:**

Currently, I use the very helpful [**exception_notification gem**](https://github.com/smartinez87/exception_notification) to email me errors.

For any API I use, I create a wrapper class in my app's `/lib` directory, and within that class I clean up what the API returns (basically just to standardize it for my needs). It's *within these wrapper classes* that I have `begin...rescue` blocks, like so:

```
begin

  # the API call, or scrape with Nokogiri here...    

rescue Errno::ECONNREFUSED, Zlib::DataError, RuntimeError, OpenURI::HTTPError => e

  # set the return value to a helpful error or something... 

end
```

As you can see, I'm rescuing from 4 different exceptions here, and the only way I'm discovering those is through trial and error.

- **Problem one:** The rescue made it so the end user's experience wasn't jarring, but I have no way of knowing that an API (or scrape) went badly, so I'm thinking I should use exception_notification's [manual sending of a  notification](https://github.com/smartinez87/exception_notification#manually-notify-of-exception) to just email myself the exception in the rescue block. **Is this a decent way of handling this?**
- **Problem two:** More than just those 4 specific exceptions might happen. Should I save myself the guesswork and just rescue from `Exception => e`, and email myself whatever `e` is?

Thanks!

**SOLUTION**

Rather than using exception_notification to email exceptions to myself in the rescue block, I went with Anthony's advice in the comments and started using [Rollbar](https://rollbar.com/).

Regarding the issue of which exceptions to rescue from, it's a better idea to [Rescue StandardError, Not Exception](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/rescue-standarderror-not-exception).

Comment: If you're not handling those errors differently, then yes `rescue => e` to catch everything is fine.  Take a look at software like `Rollbar` that will roll this stuff up for you as your inbox might become overwhelmed!

Comment: @Anthony I'll definitely have a look at Rollbar to save my inbox, thanks for that! Regarding rescuing, I think it's more important to just uniformly show a user, "Sorry, couldn't get your data" and for me to know what went wrong. In that case, I suppose it's not a bad practice for me to catch all exceptions, right?

Comment: Yep - I think that's a good place to start.